# decrease input width (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to decrease middle name input field but i can't get it work. It only works at xs screen (picture below).

[image: Picture]

```
<div class="row">            
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="userForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="first" class="control-label">Child's Name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="col-xs-9 col-sm-5"> 
                        <input  type="text" class="form-control" id='first' name="first" >
                        <label for ="first">First </label>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3 col-sm-2"  id='mi' name="mi" >
                        <label for ="mi">MI</label>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="col-xs-9 col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id = "last" name="last" >
                        <label for="last"> Last </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>            
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried to modify CSS definitions? No one will write the code for you.

Comment: try removing all col-xs classes

Comment: Check your closing `</div>` and `</form>` tags because you miss some of them. I try to edit them but in your IDE it should be easier to notice when you properly close each tag.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is wrong please check again.you end the `</form>` before end other tag. and again read how to use bootstrap form. [help this link](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php).

Answer (score 0):

remove span and add col-sm-4 to div

`

```
            <div class="form-group required">
                <label for="first" class="control-label">Child's Name</label>
                <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='first' name="first">
                    <label for="first">First </label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group col-sm-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id='mi' name="mi">
                    <label for="mi">MI</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group col-sm-4">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="last" name="last">
                    <label for="last"> Last </label>

                </div>
                <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.first.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                    <p ng-message="required">Child's First Name is required.</p>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>`
```